# How do I fix this Fortran text parser for Lapack within Gem5

Tags: fortran, lapack, gem5

After about an hour, I need to ask for some help.

I've downloaded the math benchmark [Lapack](https://github.com/Reference-LAPACK/lapack) to run within a few CPU configurations for the [simulation tool Gem5](https://gem5.org/), which lets you build X86 computers and run binaries.

To aid in my boostrapping of this simulation, the entire codebase runs within a Docker container on top of WSL2 on my Windows 10 PC. The hierarchy is rather deep, but this has been working well for me.

One issue with Lapack is that it doesn't make the generated binaries very transparent. It tries to hide everything behind `make` commands. While this works most of the time, I do need to have a binary filepath that I can then use in my Gem5 configuration.

After a bit of searching around, I found the binaries. To run them, you need to provide an input file with a bunch of setup params. Here's how I run this in my Docker container:

```
./LIN/xlintstrfz < ztest_rfp.in

 Tests of the COMPLEX*16 LAPACK RFP routines 
 LAPACK VERSION 3.*.0

 The following parameter values will be used:
    N   :       0     1     2     3     5     6    10    11    50
    NRHS:       1     2    15
    TYPE:       1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9

 Routines pass computational tests if test ratio is less than   30.00

 Relative machine underflow is taken to be    0.222507-307
 Relative machine overflow  is taken to be    0.179769+309
 Relative machine precision is taken to be    0.111022D-15

 COMPLEX*16 RFP routines passed the tests of the error exits

 All tests for ZPF drivers  passed the threshold (   2304 tests run)
 All tests for ZLANHF auxiliary routine passed the threshold (   384 tests run)
 All tests for the RFP conversion routines passed (   72 tests run)
 All tests for ZTFSM auxiliary routine passed the threshold (  7776 tests run)
 All tests for ZHFRK auxiliary routine passed the threshold (   2592 tests run)

 End of tests
 Total time used =         0.71 seconds
```

Now I need to translate this into my Gem5 configuration, which is a Python script.

```
binary = os.path.join(
    thispath,
    "../../../",
    "tests/test-progs/lapack/TESTING/LIN/xlintstrfz",
)

process = Process()
process.cmd = [binary]
process.input = 'tests/test-progs/lapack/TESTING/ztest_rfp.in'
```

When I run this, the program is found and the input file does start to be processed:

```
gem5 Simulator System.  https://www.gem5.org
gem5 is copyrighted software; use the --copyright option for details.

gem5 version 22.1.0.0
gem5 compiled May 18 2023 15:42:00
gem5 started May 24 2023 00:42:19
gem5 executing on 8fa8d1b910d8, pid 26054
command line: build/GCN3_X86/gem5.opt configs/learning_gem5/part1/simple.py

Global frequency set at 1000000000000 ticks per second
build/GCN3_X86/base/statistics.hh:280: warn: One of the stats is a legacy stat. Legacy stat is a stat that does not belong to any statistics::Group. Legacy stat is deprecated.
0: system.remote_gdb: listening for remote gdb on port 7008
Beginning simulation!
build/GCN3_X86/sim/simulate.cc:192: info: Entering event queue @ 0.  Starting simulation...

 Tests of the COMPLEX*16 LAPACK RFP routines 
 LAPACK VERSION 3.*.0

 The following parameter values will be used:
    N   :       0     1     2     3     5     6    10    11    50
build/GCN3_X86/sim/mem_state.cc:443: info: Increasing stack size by one page.
At line 166 of file zchkrfp.f (unit = 5, file = 'stdin')
Fortran runtime error: Bad integer for item 3 in list input

Error termination.
```

As you can see, it does start to run the same binary and gets the first lines before it crashes only in the Gem5 environment.

Going to the offending file, the section related to the NRHS is (starting at line 153 of `zchkrpf.f`):

```
*
*     Read the values of NRHS
*
      READ( NIN, FMT = * )NNS
      IF( NNS.LT.1 ) THEN
         WRITE( NOUT, FMT = 9996 )' NNS', NNS, 1
         NNS = 0
         FATAL = .TRUE.
      ELSE IF( NNS.GT.MAXIN ) THEN
         WRITE( NOUT, FMT = 9995 )' NNS', NNS, MAXIN
         NNS = 0
         FATAL = .TRUE.
      END IF
      READ( NIN, FMT = * )( NSVAL( I ), I = 1, NNS )
      DO 30 I = 1, NNS
         IF( NSVAL( I ).LT.0 ) THEN
            WRITE( NOUT, FMT = 9996 )'NRHS', NSVAL( I ), 0
            FATAL = .TRUE.
         ELSE IF( NSVAL( I ).GT.MAXRHS ) THEN
            WRITE( NOUT, FMT = 9995 )'NRHS', NSVAL( I ), MAXRHS
            FATAL = .TRUE.
         END IF
   30 CONTINUE
      IF( NNS.GT.0 )
     $   WRITE( NOUT, FMT = 9993 )'NRHS', ( NSVAL( I ), I = 1, NNS )
*
```

It seems to crash at the line `READ( NIN, FMT = * )( NSVAL( I ), I = 1, NNS )` but I cannot figure out why it would fail in one environment and not the other.

The contents of `ztest_rfp.in` are as follows:

```
Data file for testing COMPLEX*16 LAPACK linear equation routines RFP format
9                              Number of values of N (at most 9)
0 1 2 3 5 6 10 11 50           Values of N
3                              Number of values of NRHS (at most 9)
1 2 15                         Values of NRHS (number of right hand sides)
9                              Number of matrix types (list types on next line if 0 < NTYPES <  9)
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9              Matrix Types
30.0                           Threshold value of test ratio
T                              Put T to test the error exits
```

I thought maybe there is some weird character processing that is different, but I don't know nearly enough about Fortran to identify what's going on. At this point I don't really know how to proceed since this does block any further work. I've poked around as best as I can without any success, so I'd appreciate anyone else's insight here.

Comment: The source of zchkrfp.f is at https://netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/df/da2/zchkrfp_8f_source.html     When I stripped out the calls to other lapack routines and compiled it with either gfortran or nagfor it could read that file without problems.

Comment: The only way that I could reproduce your error message was to put a non-numeric character in the input file before the third item of the "values of N". Can you try opening the input file file with a (simple) editor, check for any spurious characters or anomalies and re-save it. Then re-run your program.

Comment: If I remove all the comments, I am able to get that code to run. Thanks for that. I have tried to check for spurious characters but VSCode doesn't seem to make that easy (running VSCode in Windows connected to a Docker in WSL might lead to some discrepancies anyway). Thanks for the suggestion.